# How to plot row data from a matlab table

Tags: matlab, plot

If i have my results at 2 rows like

```
 
       methode1     m2       m3        m4
data1  .456       .567      .987      .654
data2  .768       .654      .546      .231
```

and i want to draw each line Separately
where two lines on the same scale

Comment: See: [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

Comment: I have edited the title to reflect you're trying to plot table rows specifically. If this is not correct please revert the edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you present your data I'm assuming you're dealing with a matlab table like this:

```
>> methode1 = [.456; .768]; m2 = [.567; .654]; m3 = [.987; .546]; m4 = [.654; .231];
>> T = table(methode1, m2, m3, m4, 'RowNames', {'data1', 'data2'})
T =   
             methode1     m2       m3       m4  
             ________    _____    _____    _____
    data1    0.456       0.567    0.987    0.654
    data2    0.768       0.654    0.546    0.231
```

and that the actual question is that you're not sure how to plot because `T('data1', :)` produces another table as opposed to numbers, and therefore `plot(T('data1', :))` doesn't work, rather than because you're just not aware of the `plot` command (if you really *aren't* aware of the `plot` command, then read about it online, you'll find lots of explanatory examples).

To use the data, you need to extract it to an array first. The command to do this is:

```
>> T_data = table2array(T)
T_data =
    0.4560    0.5670    0.9870    0.6540
    0.7680    0.6540    0.5460    0.2310
```

You can now plot like a normal array, e.g.

```
>> plot(T_data(1,:), 'ro-');
>> hold on                  
>> plot(T_data(2,:), 'gd--');
>> hold off
```

The `hold` command is what allows you to have more than one plots on the same figure window.

Comment: The conversion isn't necessary, `T{1, :} == T_data(1,:)`

Comment: Thanks @excaza; I don't work with tables, good to know. Comparing with cells, syntax makes sense come to think of it; I should have guessed! :)

Comment: Thank you very much Tasos and excaza

Comment: but how to write the title of each axis and write what each line refer to

Comment: @AsmaaDaoud here's [how to add a title, axis labels and a legend](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/add-title-axis-labels-and-legend-to-graph.html) from the matlab docs. It's very straightforward. If you're new to plotting in general, have a look at the [basics from the main documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics.html). :)